# Make first background on top of the second background

Tags: css

I have this setup where I have two background. And I wanted the first background on top of the second background.

```css
#first-background {
  background: url("/assets/first-bg.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#second-background {
  background: url("/assets/second-bg.svg") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="first-background">
  <div id="second background">
    Some content
  </div>
</div>
```

The second background is an svg

Answer (score 0):

If you want first background on top of the second background use both inside a single class like this :

```
 #example {
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    background-image: url("/assets/first-bg.png"), ("/assets/second-bg.svg");
    background-position:
        center bottom,  /* this positions the first image */
        left top; /* this positions the second image */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }
```